# jQuery continuously running an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, joomla, dom-events

I have the following code which checks for the id of the active tab BUT only once when the page initially loads.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         var id_of_tab = jQuery('#member-registration .tab-pane.active').attr('id');
         console.log(id_of_tab);
});
```

I need this code to continuously check for the id of the active tab, (as there are various ways in which the user can make this tab active, and I have tried many click and hover events but ive found issues with all of them).

Rather than firing on a click/hover (such as the example below) the code needs to simple needs to keep running and to change the variable value if the active tab changes.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $( ".view-registration" ).hover(
      function() {  
         var id_of_tab = jQuery('#member-registration .tab-pane.active').attr('id');
         console.log(id_of_tab);
      });
});
```

I'm struggling on this one!

Comment: How can users interact with the tab? One way could be setting up an interval ([`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)) but I would not recommend that

Comment: `jQuery('#member-registration...` is already selecting by ID. And there should only be one. Make IDs are unique

Comment: Are these JQueryUI tabs?  If so there is an activate event.

Comment: @empiric thanks for your time/help! Users could use a tab key on the keyboard, there is a next button and also a the tab which can be clicked, also baring in mind users on different devices.

Comment: @jimmywiddle as Rich Linnell asked, is this some sort of plugin or joomla functionallity?

Comment: Yes this is joomla functionality, the user registration form, also using the easyprofile component which extends joomlas registration rather than rewritting it.

Comment: @theblindprophet Many thanks!... there is only 1 #member-registration on the page

Comment: An element should have only one ID. So your `attr()` should be returning "member-registration"

Comment: @theblindprophet thanks again! ..the element has only 1 ID "member-registration"

Answer (score 0):

You can bind multiple events on one function handler.
The 4 I suggest here are only suggestion for the code example`
It's up to you to determine the right events to bind.

See list here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#member-registration" ).bind("change mouseover click input",function(){  
         var id_of_tab = $(this).attr('id');    // Will alway return #member-registration
         console.log(id_of_tab);

         // Suggested console message ;)
         console.log("An event occured on #member-registration");

         // Maybe a check for the `active` class?
         if( $(this).hasClass("active") ){
            console.log("#member-registration is active.");
         }
      });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks!!!!!!!! You know this works great (well I had to make a couple of minor changes)  BUT except for on my phone (any touch screen device)... any ideas, for something that might work on these also?

Comment: I know of `tap`, `touchstart` and `touchend`... List here : https://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/